# How to validate dynamically defined grammar elements in PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am implementing a parser for a fairly complex grammar using PyParsing. (Which, if I may add, is really a pleasure to use!)

The grammar is somewhat 'dynamic' in that allows for the definition of (various) alphabets, which in turn define the elements allowed in other definitions. As an example:

```
alphabet: a b c
lists:
s1 = a b
s2 = b c x
```

Here, `alphabet` is meant to define what elements are allowed in the `lists` definitions. E.g., `s1` would be valid, but `s2` contains an invalid `x`.

A simple PyParsing parser without that kind of validation could look like this:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, lineEnd, Word, alphanums,\
    OneOrMore, Group, Suppress, dictOf

def fixedToken(literal):
    return Suppress(Literal(literal))

Element = Word(alphanums)

Alphabet = Group(OneOrMore(~lineEnd + Element))
AlphaDef = fixedToken("alphabet:") + Alphabet

ListLine = OneOrMore(~lineEnd + Element)
Lists = dictOf(Word(alphanums) + fixedToken("="), ListLine)

Start = AlphaDef + fixedToken("lists:") + Lists

if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = """
    alphabet: a b c
    lists:
    s1 = a b
    s2 = b c x
    """

    res = Start.parseString(data)
    for k, v in sorted(res.items()):
        print k, "=", v
```

This will parse & give the output:

```
Alphabet= set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
s1 = ['a', 'b']
s2 = ['b', 'c', 'x']
```

However, I would like the parser to raise a ParseException (or similar) for `s2`, since it contains the invalid `x`. Ideally, I would like to be able to make the definition of `ListLine` to say something like: `OneOrMore(oneOf(Alphabet))` - but evidently, that would require some dynamic interpretation which can only be done once `Alphabet` has actually been parsed & assembled.

One solution I found was to add parse actions to 1. remember the alphabet and 2. validate the lines:

```
# ...
Alphabet = Group(OneOrMore(~lineEnd + Element))
def alphaHold(toks):
    alphaHold.alpha = set(*toks)
    print "Alphabet=", alphaHold.alpha
Alphabet.addParseAction(alphaHold)

AlphaDef = fixedToken("alphabet:") + Alphabet

ListLine = OneOrMore(~lineEnd + Element)
def lineValidate(toks):
    unknown = set(toks).difference(alphaHold.alpha)
    if len(unknown):
        msg= "Unknown element(s): {}".format(unknown)
        print msg
        raise ParseException(msg)
ListLine.addParseAction(lineValidate)
# ...
```

This gives almost the desired output:

```
Alphabet= set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
Unknown element(s): set(['x'])
s1 = ['a', 'b']
```

But unfortunately, PyParsing catches Exceptions thrown from parse actions, so this approach fails on a technicality. Is there another way to achieve this within PyParsing which I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already pretty close to having this working. There are a number of cases where a pyparsing parser dynamically adjusts itself based on text that was previously parsed. The trick is to use a `Forward` placeholder expression, and then insert the desired values into the placeholder as part of a parse action (*very* close to what you have in place now).  Like this:

```
Element = Forward()

Alphabet = OneOrMore(~lineEnd + oneOf(list(alphas)))
def alphaHold(toks):
    Element << oneOf(toks.asList())
Alphabet.setParseAction(alphaHold)
```

From here, I think the rest of your code works fairly well as-is. Actually, you won't even need the line validating function, as pyparsing will only match valid element names as elements using this method.

You might find that pyparsing's error reporting is a little fuzzy. You can get things to be a little better using '-' instead of '+' in some judicious places. Since pyparsing uses ParseExceptions for all of its internal signalling of expression matches/mismatches, it does not automatically recognize when you have gotten into a defined expression, but then have an invalid match on a contained expression. You can tell pyparsing to detect this using the '-' operator, like this:

```
ListDef = listName + '=' - OneOrMore(~lineEnd + Element)
```

Once pyparsing gets a name and an '=' sign, then any invalid Element found will immediately raise a `ParseSyntaxException`, which will stop pyparsing's scan of the text at that point, and report the exception at the location of the invalid element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! "Forward" was exactly the kind of thing I had been looking for.